# Trigger as check constraint for integrity

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

I have to fix some problems in an old `MS SQL` database, autocreated by entityframework 4. Let's take as example the following tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE a (
 id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 date datetime NOT NULL,
 client_id int NOT NULL //references to clients table
 -- other properties related to entity a
);
```

This is a sort of an abstract entity, actually I have 8 sub-tables which define the type which include some other properties. Let's take as example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE b (
 id int NOT NULL PRIMARY FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES a (id)
 -- other properties related to entity b
);

CREATE TABLE c (
 id int NOT NULL PRIMARY FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES a (id)
 -- other properties related to entity c
);
```

That said, a client can have only one b or c (or both) per day, the ideal constraint would be an `UNIQUE` constraint but due to the properties being in different tables it is not possible (based on my knowledge). The solution I adopted is to create triggers, which check the uniqueness of each subtype:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_b_upsert
ON b
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS  
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM a a
        JOIN b b ON a.id = b.id
        WHERE a.client_id IN (
            SELECT client_id
            FROM a a
            JOIN inserted i ON a.id = i.id
        ) AND date IN (
            SELECT date
            FROM a a
            JOIN inserted i ON a.id = i.id
        )
        GROUP BY date, client_id
        HAVING count(*) > 1
    
    )
   BEGIN
      RAISERROR ('not allowed.', 10, 1)
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   END
```

and the same for `c`.

```sql
INSERT INTO a (id, date, client_id) VALUES (1, '2050-01-01', 1);
INSERT INTO b (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO a (id, date, client_id) VALUES (2, '2050-01-01', 1);
INSERT INTO b (id) VALUES (2); -- should raise error
```

```sql
INSERT INTO a (id, date, client_id) VALUES (1, '2050-01-01', 1);
INSERT INTO b (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO a (id, date, client_id) VALUES (2, '2050-01-01', 1);
INSERT INTO c (id) VALUES (2); -- should work
```

```sql
INSERT INTO a (id, date, client_id) VALUES (1, '2050-01-01', 1);
INSERT INTO a (id, date, client_id) VALUES (2, '2050-01-02', 1);
INSERT INTO a (id, date, client_id) VALUES (3, '2050-01-01', 1);
INSERT INTO a (id, date, client_id) VALUES (4, '2050-01-02', 1);
INSERT INTO b (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO b (id) VALUES (2); -- should work
INSERT INTO c (id) VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO c (id) VALUES (4); -- should work
```

Because I am no really familiar with MS SQL, I would like to know if the approach is correct  or not, and if there are some performance issues/improvments.

**Edit:**
@GarethD has shown a brillant solution to my problem, but I have another case of trigger I need to improve, if possible. Let's take the same table `a` and define two new ones:

```sql
-- another table, different from a, which as well references the client
CREATE TABLE e (
 id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 client_id int NOT NULL //references to clients table
 -- other properties related to entity e
);

CREATE TABLE d (
 id int NOT NULL PRIMARY FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES a (id)
 e_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES e (id)
 -- other properties related to entity d
);
```

As you can see, the structure allows to insert a record in `a`, `d` connected by a `e`, where `a.client_id` could be different from `e.client_id`. This scenario has to be denied. I defined a simple trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_d_upsert
ON d
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS     
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM a a
        JOIN inserted i ON a.id = i.id
        JOIN e e on e.id = i.e_id
        WHERE e.client_id != a.client_id
    
    )
   BEGIN
      RAISERROR ('Conflict client_id.', 10, 1)
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   END
```

Any hints for a nicer solution?

Comment: Should your foreign keys be referencing table a rather than table b? i.e. (`FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES b (id)`)?

Comment: Sorry didn't see this comment, I think to have already corrected it... right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never been a fan of using triggers where I can avoid them, so I would personally use indexed views here to manage the uniqueness, one for each child table:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.UniqueB
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT a.client_id, a.date
FROM dbo.a 
INNER JOIN dbo.b ON b.id = a.id;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UQ_UniqueB__clientid_date ON dbo.UniqueB (client_id, date);
```

This will constrain your records to be unique in the same way as the trigger but in my opinion is a more elegant solution, and although not tested I expect it would be more efficient too. An attempt to insert a duplicate would generate a message such as:

> Msg 2601 Level 14 State 1 Line 1 
> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.UniqueB' with unique index 'UQ_UniqueB__clientid_date'. The duplicate key value is (1, Jan  1 2050 12:00AM).

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RHeYDBmz)**

### ADDENDUM

Firstly, please don't edit your questions to ask a second question, just ask a whole new question and if necessary link back to the first one to provide additional context.

But to actually answer your question while I struggle to think of a real usecase for this, the way I think I would deal with this scenario is to actually include the `client_id` column in the table `d`. This does introduce redundancy, but it's a trade off I personally would be willing to make. To make this work fully you also need additional unique constraints on table a and table e:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.a (
 id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 date datetime NOT NULL,
 client_id int NOT NULL ,
  UNIQUE(id, client_id)
);

CREATE TABLE e (
 id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 client_id int NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE(id, client_id)
);
```

With these in place you can now reference these in table d:

```
CREATE TABLE d (
 id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.a (id),
 e_id int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.e (id),
 client_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (id,client_id) REFERENCES dbo.a (id, client_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (e_id,client_id) REFERENCES dbo.e (id, client_id)
);
```

This means that an attempt to add mis-matching client_ids to table d will result in a foreign key error to either table `a` or table `d`.

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1PlNEGnr)**

The benefit of this approach over a trigger is that it captures all changes. If you only put your trigger on table `d`, you won't capture other changes, for example even with the trigger in place the following queries runs OK:

```
UPDATE a
SET client_id =2
WHERE id =1;
```

Which then leaves mis-matching records. The same would be true of an update to table `e`.

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8-ikU64b)**

Comment: Great. Just a question regarding the name of the index. What does the prefix UQ stand for? Particular meaning?

Comment: @Emaborsa Conventionally used as a prefix in the name of a unique constraint or index

Comment: I understand. I updated my question with another scenario.

Comment: I did not create a new one, because it is almost the same, I thought it would be rejected. However, I am aware of the redundant data, but unfortunately I cannot change the structure of the tables, it would require to much effort and since in the next months/years we will rewrite the entire application, the constraints I am defining now are just a temporarely workaround.  Your `UNIQUE (id, client_id)` on both tables is wrong, I can have more `a`s and `d`s for the same client.

Comment: It is not wrong, it includes `id` which is by definition unique as it is the primary key. So you can still have multiple rows for the same client because the id will be different for each. If your concern over changing the tables is breaking existing insert scripts then you can use a trigger to auto-populate the `client_id` column and keep the constraints ([example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/j10ZFHSa)). This should mean existing inserts still work, updates, selects, won't be impacted as you can just not select/update this column. This covers the problem of updates to either table `a` or `e`

Comment: If you can't do this then I think your only option is the trigger you have said, but you need to also put a trigger on `a` and `e` to prevent updates to the `client_id` in these tables causing mis-matching records.

Comment: @GarethD How would you do it on Postgres? Unique indexes are not supported on views.

Comment: [Unique indexes are supported on materialised views](https://dbfiddle.uk/R3aDxzQs),however these do not automatically refresh when data is added to the main tables and would not work in the same way as SQL Server. The honest answer is I don't know as I am not particularly familiar with Postgresql. A trigger may be required to automatically refresh the view, but in that case you may as well just go with your original solution of validating the data with a trigger - it will perform better than refreshing the view with every update/insert